# How to do subtotal using tabulate in python

Tags: pandas, python-2.7, aggregate, tabulate

I am using tabulate in my program to get decision table as depicted below. What i want to achieve to get subtotal on both column side and row side. Is that possible in python

```
+-------+----------+---------+----------+---------+----------+

| Env   |   xsmall |   small |   medium |   large |   xlarge |

|-------+----------+---------+----------+---------+----------|

| dev   |        2 |       4 |        6 |       1 |        2 |

| prod  |        1 |       9 |        4 |       0 |        0 |

| qa    |        0 |      10 |        1 |       0 |        1 |

| uat   |        0 |       0 |        2 |       0 |        0 |

+-------+----------+---------+----------+---------+----------+
```

I want to get subtotal like this
Row 2+4+6+1+2 =15 and so on
Column 2+1+0+0 = 3

```
+-------+----------+---------+----------+---------+----------+---------

| Env   |   xsmall |   small |   medium |   large |   xlarge |Sub Total

|-------+----------+---------+----------+---------+----------+----------

| dev   |        2 |       4 |        6 |       1 |        2 |15

| prod  |        1 |       9 |        4 |       0 |        0 |14

| qa    |        0 |      10 |        1 |       0 |        1 |12

| uat   |        0 |       0 |        2 |       0 |        0 |2

+-------+----------+---------+----------+---------+----------+--------
|SubTotal|        3 |       23|        13|       1 |        3|43
```

Will appreciate your help!